# Wrapping my gulpfile in an immediately-invoked function expression

Tags: javascript, gulp, iife

Looking at my gulpfile I just realized I must be declaring all of my variables on the global scope.

My gulpfile looks pretty typical (not unlike [this one](https://gist.github.com/mikaelbr/8425025)), with a bunch of `var`s declared at the top of the file.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserify = require('gulp-browserify');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var less = require('gulp-less');
var refresh = require('gulp-livereload');
var minifyCSS = require('gulp-minify-css');
```

But this suggests to me that all of these `var`s at the top of the file are just being slapped onto the global object.

Am I being dumb?
Should I be wrapping my gulpfile in an IIFE?

And if so, why am I not seeing examples of a gulpfile within an IIFE anywhere online?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

gulpfile runs in node, not in browser. In browser these variables would be defined as global. In node this is different. Right from the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global)

> The top-level scope is not the global scope; var something inside a Node module will be local to that module

So it is OK to define variables without IIFE in gulpfile

Comment: Exactly the understanding I needed.  Thanks Zhegan!

Answer (score 2):

Remember that gulp runs in node an in node the behavior of globals is different than the browser.

> In browsers, the top-level scope is the global scope. That means that in browsers if you're in the global scope var something will define a global variable. In Node this is different. The top-level scope is not the global scope; var something inside a Node module will be local to that module.

So those variables are not globals. Node works a little different than the browser so you should read the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/) to learn the difference